# Google WALS Trainer Division by Zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Google's code from "[Building a Recommendation System in TensorFlow: Overview](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-overview)" and while running their implementation of their WALS Algorithm, I'm recieving this error:

> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
>     frac = np.array(1.0/(data > 0.0).sum(axis))

This can be seen in context on line 94 of the code: [Google's Github WALS Algorithm](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-recommendation-wals/blob/master/wals_ml_engine/trainer/wals.py).

The odd thing is, I do not always get this error. The data set I'm using only gets larger over time, so I do not believe this is happening because there is not enough data. I'm pretty sure that line of code is meaning to say calculate the reciprocal if the number is greater than zero, but leave it as zero if it is zero, but does not work as intended in the "leave zero as zero case". If this statement is not doing this, can someone tell me why `data > 0.0` doesn't suffice and how to change it so it does? (note data is a matrix)

Answer (score 2):

We can use np errstate to ignore division by zero errors

with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        frac = np.array(1.0/(data).sum(axis))